# How to construct a restriction for a blending problem that has 2 inputs that are blended, and as result we get 2 outputs?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling, integer-programming

THE PROBLEM

A refinery has 10 million barrels of type A crude and 6 million barrels of
Type B crude oil. The refinery has 3 plants to produce Gasoline (it makes a profit
of 2 USD / barrel) and Naphtha (makes a profit of 1 USD / barrel) with the following
features:

$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
 & Input  & { Input } & { Output } & { Output } \\
\hline \text { plant } & \text { A } & \text { B } & \text { Gasoline } & \text { Naphtha } \\
\hline 1 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
\hline 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline 3 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The data in the table above means that, for example, if 3 barrels of crude oil type A and 5 barrels of type B crude enter plant 1, you can get 4 barrels of Gasoline and 3 barrels of Naphtha.

MY SOLUTION:
You can find my solution attempt here [How to construct the linear programing representation of a blending problem?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/how-to-construct-the-linear-programing-representation-of-a-blending-problem)

Regarding the possible solution, it is evident that the program will be sending all of the crudes A and B to plant 3 to maximize the profit since we need 5 times of crude A and 3 times of crude B to produce 3 barrels of Gasoline and 4 barrels of Naphtha. I said, "evident" because processing all of the raw material will allow having 2 "batches" at plant 3, blending 5 million of A and 3 million of B each time, and using all the raw material.

I'm having an issue traducing my logic into a restriction.

**DOUBT:**

As you can see in the table, for plant 1, we will have a restriction for the needed combinations of inputs to get a certain amount of Gasoline and Naphtha as a result of the blending of Crude A and Crude B:

\begin{align}
3A+5B &\geq 4G+3N
\end{align}

Taking this with my decision variables we'll have:
\begin{align}
3x_{A,1}+5x_{B,1}=4y_{G,1}+3y_{N,1}
\end{align}
where:
\begin{align}
x_{ij} \text{ the Qty of crude } i \in \{A,B\} \text{ to plant } j \in \{1,2,3\} \\
y_{kj} \text{ the Qty of final product } k \in \{G,N\} \text{ produced by plant } j \in \{1,2,3\}
\end{align}

So I'll need to establish a coefficient of proportions required for each plant, considering that we need 2 inputs with specific ratios for each plant to get 2 final products.

Thank you for any correction and any guidance with this.

Comment: Your first two constraints are wrong, and suggest a misunderstanding of the data table. Think in terms of "batches". What does a batch consume, and what does it produce.

Comment: Professor @prubin, my new formulation is: DVs: $x_{i}$ the # of batches of plant $i \in J$; Obj max profit $z=11x_{1}+3x_{2}+10x_{3}$ where the coeff. are the profit/batches for each plant; Constraint: $5x_{1}+1x_{2}+3x_{3} \leq 10e^6$ where the coeff. are the qty of A needed for $x_{i}$ and 10^6 is the available # of barrels of A; $3x_{1}+1x_{2}+5x_{3} \leq 6e^6$ where the coefficients are the qty of B needed for $x_{i}$  and 6e^6 is the available # of barrels of  B; $x_{i} \geq 0$ Non-negativity constraint of DVs. What do you think of my new formulation? Thank for your help. Happy new year!

Comment: I would avoid the large right-hand side values by putting things in millions of barrels / batches / dollars, but your formulation is correct. (1e6 is not really a problem here, but mixing very large and not-so-large coefficients has been known to cause solvers some problems with numerical accuracy, so I err on the side of caution.)